# maven multi environment using profile self-defined properties could not be use in build finalName

Tags: java, maven

In a multienvironment, I use maven profiles to distinguish them. It works good.

However, one of the properties defined in each profile is the name of package. Running `maven package -Pdev` gives error:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.2:war (default-war) on project lottery-backend: The parameters 'warName' for goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.2:war are missing or invalid -> [Help 1]
```

Pom is very long, taking out the issue related part only:

```
<profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>pub</id>
            <properties>
                <rp.build.warname>pub-pakcage</rp.build.warname>
                ...
        <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
            <properties>
                <rp.build.warname>dev-pakcage</rp.build.warname>
                ...
<profiles>
<build>
    <finalName>${rp.build.warname}</finalName>
</build>
```

If I write name of package, no matter pub-package or dev-package instead of using `${rp.build.warname}`, it would work. Just cannot use self-defined property for `finalName`. Why?

Comment: Try to run `mvn help:all-profiles` on your project and check whether the `dev` profile is actually available

Comment: Setting the finalName is only valid for the `target` folder but will not change the name which will be used for the deployment into a repository. Apart from that i think [this](https://github.com/khmarbaise/multienv-maven-plugin) could help.